# Getting indexes where timedifferences are not a given unit

Tags: python, pandas

I have to manually insert some information on my computer and therefore I have to check if all data are typed correctly.

My data looks like this:

```
timestamp,value
2015-03-02 15:00:45,1
2015-03-02 15:01:00,2
2015-03-02 15:01:15,3
2015-03-02 15:01:30,4
2015-03-02 15:01:45,5
2015-03-02 15:02:00,6
2015-03-02 15:02:15,7
2015-03-02 15:02:30,8
2015-03-02 15:02:45,9
2015-03-02 15:03:00,10
2015-03-02 15:03:15,11
2015-03-02 15:03:30,12
2015-03-02 15:03:45,13
2015-03-02 15:04:00,14
2015-03-02 15:04:15,15
2015-03-02 15:04:30,16
2015-03-02 15:04:45,17
2015-03-02 15:05:00,18
2015-03-02 17:00:45,19
2015-03-02 17:01:00,20
2015-03-02 17:01:15,21
2015-03-02 17:01:30,22
2015-03-02 17:01:45,23
2015-03-02 17:02:00,24
2015-03-02 17:02:15,25
2015-03-02 17:02:30,26
2015-03-02 17:02:45,27
2015-03-02 17:03:00,28
2015-03-02 17:03:15,29
2015-03-02 17:03:30,30
2015-03-02 17:03:45,31
2015-03-02 17:04:00,32
2015-03-02 17:04:15,33
2015-03-02 17:04:30,34
2015-03-02 17:44:15,33
2015-03-02 17:44:30,34
2015-03-02 17:44:45,35
2015-03-02 17:45:00,36
2015-03-02 17:45:15,37
2015-03-02 17:45:30,38
2015-03-02 17:45:45,39
2015-03-02 17:46:00,40
2015-03-02 17:46:15,41
2015-03-17 15:00:45,1
2015-03-17 15:01:00,2
2015-03-17 15:01:15,3
2015-03-17 15:01:30,4
2015-03-17 15:01:45,5
2015-03-17 15:02:00,6
2015-03-17 15:02:15,7
2015-03-17 15:02:30,8
2015-03-17 15:02:45,9
2015-03-17 15:03:00,10
2015-03-17 15:03:15,11
2015-03-17 15:03:30,12
2015-03-17 15:03:45,13
2015-03-17 15:04:00,14
2015-03-17 15:04:15,15
2015-03-17 15:04:30,16
2015-03-17 15:04:45,17
2015-03-17 15:05:00,18
2015-03-17 17:00:45,19
2015-03-17 17:01:00,20
2015-03-17 17:01:15,21
2015-03-17 17:01:30,22
2015-03-17 17:01:45,23
2015-03-17 17:02:00,24
2015-03-17 17:02:15,25
2015-03-17 17:02:30,26
2015-03-17 17:02:45,27
2015-03-17 17:03:00,28
2015-03-17 17:03:15,29
2015-03-17 17:03:30,30
2015-03-17 17:03:45,31
2015-03-17 17:04:00,32
2015-03-17 17:04:15,33
2015-03-17 17:04:30,34
2015-03-17 17:44:15,33
2015-03-17 17:44:30,34
2015-03-17 17:44:45,35
2015-03-17 17:45:00,36
2015-03-17 17:45:15,37
2015-03-17 17:45:30,38
2015-03-17 17:45:45,39
2015-03-17 17:46:00,40
2015-03-17 17:46:15,41
```

My desired output should look like this:
The odd number indicates the beginning of an interval, the 
even one the end (still included).

```
2015-03-02 15:00:45,1
2015-03-02 15:05:00,18
2015-03-02 17:00:45,19
2015-03-02 17:04:30,34
2015-03-02 17:44:15,33
2015-03-02 17:46:15,41
2015-03-17 15:00:45,1
2015-03-17 15:05:00,18
2015-03-17 17:00:45,19
2015-03-17 17:04:30,34
2015-03-17 17:44:15,33
2015-03-17 17:46:15,41
```

With this method we can see if data transaction and retyping worked.

My attempts up to here are not working as they do not have all breakpoints correctly in.

```
mintime = pd.to_datetime(tiere.loc[(tiere.timestamp.shift(-1)-tiere.timestamp)>"00:01:00","timestamp"].values[0:],format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").sort_values()
#add to time max and get unique timestamps and sort them works only if tiere resample is NOT ON!!!
maxtime = pd.to_datetime(tiere.loc[(tiere.timestamp-tiere.timestamp.shift(1))>"00:01:00","timestamp"].values[0:],format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").sort_values()
#add to time min and get unique timestamps and sort them. works only if tiere resample is NOT ON!!!
min2 = (pd.to_datetime(tiere.loc[(tiere.timestamp.shift(1)-tiere.timestamp)>"00:01:00","timestamp"].values[0:],format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").sort_values())
#add to time max and get unique timestamps and sort them works only if tiere resample is NOT ON!!!
max2 = (pd.to_datetime(tiere.loc[(tiere.timestamp-tiere.timestamp.shift(-1))>"00:01:00","timestamp"].values[0:],format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").sort_values())
breakpoints = mintime.union(mintimestamp_tiere).union(min2).union(maxtime).union(maxtimestamp_tiere).union(forgottentimedates).union(max2).delete(7)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html), instead of `shift` with subtract, and create a `mask` with [`Timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html) to compare the difference to a minute (or any time difference). To be sure to get the first and last row of the dataframe, the symbol `~` is used to get the reverse of the selection where the difference is less than a minute, such as:

```
tiere.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(tiere.timestamp) #convert the data to datetime first

mask = (~(tiere.timestamp.diff() < pd.Timedelta(minutes=1))|
        ~(tiere.timestamp.diff(-1).abs() < pd.Timedelta(minutes=1)))
breakpoints = tiere[mask]

print (breakpoints )
             timestamp  value
0  2015-03-02 15:00:45      1
17 2015-03-02 15:05:00     18
18 2015-03-02 17:00:45     19
33 2015-03-02 17:04:30     34
34 2015-03-02 17:44:15     33
42 2015-03-02 17:46:15     41
43 2015-03-17 15:00:45      1
60 2015-03-17 15:05:00     18
61 2015-03-17 17:00:45     19
76 2015-03-17 17:04:30     34
77 2015-03-17 17:44:15     33
85 2015-03-17 17:46:15     41
```

Comment: Very elegant solution